# Keybinding keys to insert custom code Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, time, macros, key-bindings

How would I go about setting up a keybinding so when I press for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> in eclipse it surrounds the selected lines with a time measurer.

Like so:

1:

```
CODE
CODE
CODE
```

2: Select three lines and press CTRL+SHIFT+T

3:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
CODE
CODE
CODE
Print.pln("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + "ms");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a template, for example:

```
long ${newName} = System.currentTimeMillis();
${line_selection}
Print.pln("Time taken: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - ${newName}) + "ms");
```

You can add this under Preferences->Java->Editor->Templates. Here you will have to give it a name, e.g. timer.

To use it, select the code press CNTRL+SPACE twice, then select timer (or whatever name you gave to the template).

Note that this will generate a name for the time variable.