# how to add user defined function in eclipse default?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

when we use eclipse

inside the class we type

"main"

then hit `CTRL+ENTER`

and suddenly whole definition of the main is written in the class file in eclipse editor

suppose i have a method

```
void myAwesomeMethod(String string)
    {
        System.out.println("===>>>Sstring is "+string);
    }
```

i want to create some short cut like say `CTRL+SHIFT+P`

which will type this whole method in my editor

how can one do it ??

or is there any library or plugin to do it in a better way ??

Comment: Do you really need ctrl+shift+p key combination? if not eclipse has editor templates for these situations like main method using ctrl+space then enter. take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11518784/keybinding-keys-to-insert-custom-code-eclipse

Comment: yeah yeah I wanted the template stuff only , thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Eclipse Editor templates, for instance [here](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Feditor%2Fref-preferences-templates.htm).